# Flutter - How to open second screen from first tab screen of bottom menu navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a home screen, there is a bottom tab bar with 4 bars. Now my concern is for the 1st tab bar.

There are different categories displayed in 1st tab bar for eg. as you can see in the screenshot there are 2 categories :

1) Category 1 (Motorcross, Road, and Accessories)
2) Popular categories

Now when I click on any of Category 1, I want the tab bar (4 tab bar) in the bottom but when I open the popular category I don't want that tab bar.

So I am stuck here.

My code snippet is below.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          child: SizedBox.expand(
            child: PageView(
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              onPageChanged: (index) {
                setState(() => currentIndex = index);
              },
              children: <Widget>[
                Products(),
                News(),
                Service(),
                Events(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/icons/bottom_center.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        focusElevation: 10,
        disabledElevation: 10,
        highlightElevation: 10,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return WorldCategories();
          }));
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: currentIndex,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
              _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            });
          },
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), title: Text("A")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), title: Text("X")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), title: Text("Y")),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit), title: Text("Z")),
          ]),
);
```

and also floatingActionButton set to top on the second screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the Products page, because it might redirect from there and cannot see the code of that Products page

Comment: Do you mean you want to see code of product page click?

Comment: just check the code i have posted

Comment: Yes, whatever you post is right. I also set that code to open full page but my main concern is about second page. How can I set bottom on that screen and also manage backpress to open first screen?

Comment: I displayed main screen and second screen. Which I want to manage.

Comment: may be we should chat :https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208572/navigation-issue

Comment: I have updated my question and also repled you in detail in  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208572/navigation-issue

Answer (score 0):

What is think is you can use the GestureDetector for the Popular categories text and on tap redirect it to your desired page.

```
 GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
              // here you make your navigation for your desired page
         Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => youPage()),
             );
              },
              child: Padding(

                child: Text(
                  'Populat Categoreies',

                ),
              ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two layouts inside products and when click motocross hide the 1st layout and display motocross layout and when clicking on popular categories 
do a page navigation like

```
Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return popularCategories();
          }));
```

Comment: but can you elaborate on how to hide 1st layout?

Comment: use a stack widget in which set products and motocross as two widgets 
wrap them with visibility widget and with that you can show or hide